# Errors parsing template: Unexpected closing tag app-post-list

Tags: node.js, angular, mean

Getting an error when I try to output my post in angular. please help to resolve this issue...

**error message**

Errors parsing template: Unexpected closing tag "app-post-list".

**my post-list.component.ts code**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: 'aap-post-list',
templateUrl: './post-list.component.html'
})

export class PostListComponent {}
```

**my post-list.component.html**

```
<mat-accordion>
   <mat-expansion-panel>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      The expansion title!
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm in an expansion panel!</p>
   </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**app.component.html code**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <app-post-create></app-post-create>
  <aap-post-list></app-post-list>
</main>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {PostCreateComponent} from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
PostCreateComponent,
HeaderComponent,
PostListComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
MatInputModule,
MatCardModule,
MatButtonModule,
MatToolbarModule,
MatExpansionModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostListComponent } from './posts/post-list/post-list.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
beforeEach(async(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostListComponent
  ],
}).compileComponents();
}));

it('should create the app', () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const app = fixture.componentInstance;
expect(app).toBeTruthy();
});

it(`should have as title 'mean-learning'`, () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
const app = fixture.componentInstance;
expect(app.title).toEqual('mean-learning');
});

it('should render title', () => {
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
fixture.detectChanges();
const compiled = fixture.nativeElement;
expect(compiled.querySelector('.content span').textContent).toContain('mean-learning app is running!');
});
});
```

[image]

Please let me know where I'm wrong and how I solve this issue.

Comment: It's a typo. In **app.component.html**, replace `<aap-post-list></app-post-list>` with `<aap-post-list></aap-post-list>`. Better yet, change the component selector to `app-post-list`.

Comment: if the problem is solved please click the solved icon on the answer

Comment: now i get this error message src/app/app.component.html:4:5 - error NG8001: 'app-post-list' is not a known element: If 'app-post-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. If 'app-post-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. <app-post-list></app-post-list> src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
templateUrl: './app.component.html', Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have done Typo in the line number **4** change `<aap-post-list>`   to `<app-post-list>` problem solved.

**app.component.html** code

```
<app-header></app-header>
<main>
  <app-post-create></app-post-create>
  <aap-post-list></app-post-list>
</main>
```

***Updated***

you have changed the `<aap-post-list> to <app-post-list>` so now go back to

```
post-list.component.ts
```

now change the **selector** to

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

```
@Component({
selector: 'aap-post-list',
templateUrl: './post-list.component.html'
})

export class PostListComponent {}
```

to

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-post-list',
templateUrl: './post-list.component.html'
})

export class PostListComponent {}
```

now it should work fine

Comment: sir  thanks for your answer I changed it but now I get this message app-post-list' is not a known element If 'app-post-list' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module. If 'app-post-list' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Comment: You declared the component as `aap-post-list`. So you should change on the declaration too (the selector).

Comment: change selector: 'aap-post-list', to  'app-post-list'

Comment: @NaveenKumar sorry I did'nt get your answer, please explain me

Comment: @ayushflitzip now check my answer